# Emulating Cmd+~ in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

Is there a way to somehow emulate **Cmd + ~** shortcut behaviour (i.e. cycling through an application windows) in Cocoa?

I was able to do this in Carbon by doing the following:

```
HICommand cmd;
cmd.attirbutes = kHICommandFromMenu;
cmd.commandID = kHICommandRotateWindowsForward;
::GetIndMenuItemWithCommandID( NULL, cmd.commandID, 1, &(cmd.menu.menuRef), &(cmd.menu.menuItemIndex));
::ProcessHICommand(&cmd);
```

But now I need to do this in Cocoa and can't find a way :)
Googled something about a "private method _cycleWindows in NSApplication", which seems to do exactly what I need, but the code

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] _cycleWindows];
```

won't compile - "wrong method signature".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using _cycleWindows is the correct thing to do. Try this:

> [NSApp sendAction:@selector(_cycleWindows:) to:nil from:nil];

Also, if you want to emulate Cmd+Shift+~ then do:

> [NSApp sendAction:@selector(_cycleWindowsBackwards:) to:nil from:nil];